# Рандомно добавить класс

Tags: javascript, html

```js
$(".rows .cell").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).parent().hasClass("row-5")) {
    $(this).addClass('success');
  }
})
```

```css
.cell {
  background: #000;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}

.success {
  background: green;
}

.danger {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rows">
  <div class="row row-5">
    <button class="cell" data-row="5"></button>
    <button class="cell" data-row="5"></button>
    <button class="cell" data-row="5"></button>
    <button class="cell" data-row="5"></button>
    <button class="cell" data-row="5"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Задача: надо сделать так, чтобы после нажатия на одну из кнопок, рандомно в одну из кнопок добавлялся класс `danger` (в рандом не включаем кнопку с классом `success`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.rows .cell').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
  $(this).addClass('success');
  var collect = $('.cell').not('.success').not('.danger'); // Берем коллекцию, исключая success и danger классы
  collect.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * collect.length)).addClass('danger'); // рандомим и добавляем
});
```

Добавил от себя .not('.danger') , думаю, что это то, что нужно.
Рандом взял отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614944/how-to-get-random-element-in-jquery

Comment: var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*10); лишняя строчка, приношу извинения.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".rows .cell").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).parent().hasClass("row-5")) {
    $(this).addClass('success');
    addDanger();
  }
});

function addDanger() {
  //* Получаем доступные ячейки
  var availableCells = $('.row-5 .cell').not('.success');
  //* Генерируем случайный индекс
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableCells.length);
  //* Навешиваем класс случайной ячейке
  availableCells.eq(randomIndex).addClass('danger');
}
```

```css
.cell {
  background: #000;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}

.success {
  background: green;
}

.danger {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rows">
  <div class="row row-5">
    <button class="cell" data-row="5"></button>
    <button class="cell" data-row="5"></button>
    <button class="cell" data-row="5"></button>
    <button class="cell" data-row="5"></button>
    <button class="cell" data-row="5"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```